# Fill array list with object of String[] with SQL table

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc

I'm currently trying to fill an array list with an object of String[] with a SQL table. I was able to get the headers of my tables using this code.

```
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            int i = 1;
            while (colCount >= i) {
                String header = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                field.add(header);
                i++;
```

However, when I'm trying to create my rows to fill the table, the array is not adding to the array list.

```
            while (rs.next()) {
                String[] row = new String[colCount];
                for (int j = 0; j <= colCount; j++) {
                    row[j] = rs.getString(j+1);
                }
                data.add(row);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }
        System.out.println(data.size());
```

For some reason when I put the "data.add(row);" statement in the for loop, it only shows the same row however many times it loops.  But it doesn't work outside of the for (I want to put it after the for loop inside the while). I'm outputting the size of the list to the console and it just returns 0.

Comment: You're ignoring any SQLException and continuing as if nothing important happened. This is not right. Are you absolutely sure that no one was being thrown? Add `throw new RuntimeException(ex);` inside the `catch` block to be sure. It must stop the program and print the answer to your problem (the exception message and stack trace) in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] row = new String[colCount];
for (int j = 0; j <= colCount; j++) {
    row[j] = rs.getString(j+1);
}
            data.add(row);
```

Dear my friends, why did you decided to write "j <= colCount" meanwhile you had created "j = 0". So your code is going to throw "SqlException". Because index of last element of result set is "colCount", but your loop passed index equals to j + 1. it means equal "colCount + 1".

As you know, you try catch SQLException but you don't do anything. So your code has been failed when first row of resultset and j = colCount + 1. It can't add anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up fixing the index and it worked fine.